# Unable to insert records in SQLite database using Entity Framework 5

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-4.1

I was trying to use SQLite database using ADO.NET Entity Framework 5 and I was able to connect to the SQLite database and was able to query records from a table in database. But When I am trying to insert a record into table the **SaveChanges** throws an exception

```
"An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."
```

Code looks like this:

```
var connectionStr = string.Format("data source={0};Version=3;UseUTF16Encoding=True;",
    fileName);
var conn = new SQLiteConnection(connectionStr);

this.personDataContext = new PersonDataContext(conn);

var persons = (from person in File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
               let p = person.Split(new[] { ',', ' ' },
                                    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
               select new Person
               {
                   ID = Convert.ToInt32(p[0]),
                   Name = p[1],
                   Address = p[2],
                   MobNo = Convert.ToInt32(p[3]),
                   PhNo = Convert.ToInt32(p[4]),
                   Designation = p[5]
               }).ToList();

if (this.personDataContext != null && this.personDataContext.Persons != null)
{
    foreach (var person in persons)
    {
      this.personDataContext.Persons.Add(person);
    }

    var saveFailed = false;

    do
    {
        try
        {
            this.personDataContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            saveFailed = true;
            ex.Entries.Single().Reload();
        }
    }
    while (saveFailed);
}
```

and when I check the inner exception, then it says that primary key is not defined. So, after defining the primary key into the table, same exception comes every time.

I am attaching the sample application [here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=BF69AAF5344E2B32!318). Use Open Db to open the sample database first and then try to import the CSV file.

I am using the Code First approach in which I have designed a Model class and connected it with the table in the SQLite database.

Please help in fixing the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please update your question with some more details? How is your create code looks like, what is the error exact error message? It's nice to have a repro solution but only a very few of the users will donwload it. And please think about the the later users: how somebody else will find your question when they have a similar problem.

Comment: Can you post the **exact text** of the inner exception message?

Comment: Inner exception is :- {"Abort due to constraint violation\r\nPerson.ID may not be NULL"}. I don't understand why this code acts weird with SQLite where as the code code works OK with SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to disable database generated identity for your key property in the `Person` class:

```cs
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public int ID { get; set; }
```

To me it looks like you want to supply key values manually (`ID = Convert.ToInt32(p[0])`) but EF won't send this value to the database because by default it expects that the `ID` value is generated in the database. If it isn't generated in the DB you get the exception. By setting the `DatabaseGeneratedOption` to `None` EF will take the value you supply and send it in the INSERT statement to the database.